# Design a layout from bottom to top

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to programm a quiz app for android. My layout should look/looks like this:
[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCCAI.png)

The problem is, when I first designed it I had no idea about layouting for different screen sizes. Now i do have an idea about it, but my question is: Can I stick the timer and points to the top, and the answers and the ad banner to the bottom to let the question textview be as big as possible? Because if I switch to a device with a resolution > 1080x1920 everything jumps to the top.

Sorry if my question had already been asked, it's my first post here, be kind please ;-)

Dave

Edit: Now I put alignParentBottom on the answers and the ad banner, and they are aligned to the bottom, but I don't know how to let the question textviews height scale automatically.

Comment: Android Studio comes with emulators for devices of all sizes. Why not try to stick things at the top and see if it changes anything?

Comment: @Forklift When I have the questions and ad banner in different layouts, i don't know how to stick them all to the bottom.

Comment: It's been a while since I used Android Studio, but IIRC for layouts, you can indicate per element that an element is directly below another. Make sure all of your anchors are pointing to the right relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` and anchor the top and bottom views using `alignParentBottom` / `alignParentTop` together with `height="wrap_content"`.
Then anchor the remaining views `above` or `below` the others, as needed, and set their height to `match_parent`.